# How to convert DateTime in different System culture?

Tags: c#, datetime, culture

I need to convert `DateTime` value in different culture format, whatever set in system.

There is not any specific TimeZone selected for converting, any culture format was using converting DateTime value.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo ukDtfi = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString(), false).DateTimeFormat;
StartingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["StartDate"].ToString(), ukDtfi);
```

I am using above code but its not working properly.
Currently I set `ar-SA` culture in my system.

Comment: What do you mean by _not working properly_? You _already_ parsing with `Convert.ToDateTime(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["StartDate"].ToString(), ukDtfi)`. Why do you generate it's string representation and parse it to `DateTime` again?

Comment: And what do you mean by "convert DateTime to different culture"? A DateTime doesn't have a culture. Your question is very unclear at the moment - we don't know what you're expecting to achieve or what happens with your current code. Ideally, provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, using hard-coded data, including expected output and actual output.

Comment: What is your `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["StartDate"].ToString()` returns exactly by the way?

Comment: Its returning "31/1/2016 12:00 AM"

Answer (score 5):

Let me clear some subjects first..

A `DateTime` instance does not have *any* timezone information and culture settings. It *just* have date and time values. Culture settings concept *only* applies when you get it's *textual* (string) representatiton.

Since you use `ar-SA` culture, your string format is not a standard date and time format for *that* culture.

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("31/1/2016 12:00 AM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-SA"));
// Throws FormatException
```

And you **can't** parse this string with `ar-SA` culture because this culture uses `ص` as a [`AMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator) since it uses [`UmAlQuraCalendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar) rather than a `GregorianCalendar`.

You can use [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) (which uses `AM` as a `AMDesignator` and uses `GregorianCalendar`) instead with [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) method with specify it's format exactly.

```
string s = "31/1/2016 12:00 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

which in your case;

```
StartingDate = DateTime.ParseExact(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["StartDate"].ToString(), 
                                   "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Its not giving me any Exceptions but, its giving wrong return value "21/4/1437 12:00:00 ص". I am selected this "31/1/2016 12:00 AM" value from Control.

Comment: @JeetBhatt A `DateTime` is _always_ in Gregorian calendar. Since you try to parse with `UmAlQuraCalendar` which is defined in `ar-SA` culture, this `ParseExact` method manipulates this to _that_ calendar value. You can see it on http://www.islamicfinder.org/dateConversion.php?mode=ger-hij&day=31&month=1&year=2016&date_result=1 link. `31/1/2016` in Gregorian is equal to `21/4/1437` in UmAlQura Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve your problem with this:

```
string myTime = DateTime.Parse("01/02/2016")
                        .ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Comment: Its giving same error, "String has not recognize valid datetime".. I set     "ar-SA" culture in my development system and then try to convert in "en-US" culture

Comment: Can you give me name for that DLLs?

Comment: At my side, everything works fine. You need to add this: using System.Globalization; @JeetBhatt