# How to get datetime input to use only hours, minutes, and seconds no microseconds

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor

I am working on a Razor view that has an input for a datetime. I would like to take the value they enter and convert it. However, in the UI it keeps showing up with microseconds and giving me validation errors when I submit.
DateTime property

```
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime Time { get; internal set; }
```

razor html

```
<div class="form-group">
<input asp-for="@Model.Time">
```

I have tried formatting it as a string an specifying to the input but it keeps showing up with the microseconds...

[image]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: How do you format it as string without the microseconds?

Comment: You can refer to this link to show datetime as you like : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @Pop I attached the error message. And this is how using a format string with this HH:mm:ss

Comment: @ZaheerAnsari that is true for formatting as a string but does not tell me how to format it in the input box ui

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time)
```

This will render `DateTime` input field with the desired format (hours, minutes, and seconds) and prevent microseconds from being displayed.

In order to solve your problem you can also try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Time, "{0:HH:mm:ss}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and in your model class:

```
public class YourModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Time { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This is very close, it is much better than what I had but there are two things.
1. The time input displays seconds but does not let me enter as input.
2. HH should be formatted as a 24 hour representation of the hour but it is giving me normal 12 hour with the AM PM option

Comment: James you need to change the culture of your datetime., You're probably using US us culture for your time. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126433/how-to-convert-datetime-in-different-system-culture I believe this might help you

Comment: @JamesCampbell I update my answer

Comment: Thisis just giving a text box for me, no longer the date input now.